# WordPress 4.7 REST API endpoints

Tags: rest-api, endpoints

So with WordPress 4.7 the REST API endpoints will be merged into the core which I'm really looking forward to.

On setting up a test site with the 4.7 beta 4 installed, I wasn't able to find the endpoints that have been available through the [REST API Plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/).

Looking at `/wp-json` I don't see any endpoints either:

```
{
    "name": "API Test",
    "description": "Eine weitere WordPress-Seite",
    "url": "http:\/\/testsite.net",
    "home": "http:\/\/testsite.net",
    "namespaces": ["oembed\/1.0"],
    "authentication": [],
    "routes": {
        "\/": {
            "namespace": "",
            "methods": ["GET"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "context": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "view"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/testsite.net\/wp-json\/"
            }
        },
        "\/oembed\/1.0": {
            "namespace": "oembed\/1.0",
            "methods": ["GET"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "namespace": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "oembed\/1.0"
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "view"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/testsite.net\/wp-json\/oembed\/1.0"
            }
        },
        "\/oembed\/1.0\/embed": {
            "namespace": "oembed\/1.0",
            "methods": ["GET"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "url": {
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "format": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "json"
                    },
                    "maxwidth": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": 600
                    }
                }
            }],
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/testsite.net\/wp-json\/oembed\/1.0\/embed"
            }
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "help": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/v2.wp-api.org\/"
        }]
    }
}
```

Do I still need the plugin or activate those endpoints in the `wp-config.php` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ticket [#38373](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38373) the following endpoints will be supported  in version 4.7.

Let me quote [Rachel Baker](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38373#comment:3):

> REST API endpoints for your WordPress content. These endpoints provide
>   machine-readable external access to your WordPress site with a clear,
>   standards-driven interface, allowing new and innovative apps for
>   interacting with your site.
>
> These endpoints support all of the following:
>
> - Posts: Read and write access to all post data, for all types of post-based data, including pages and media.
> - Comments: Read and write access to all comment data. This includes pingbacks and trackbacks.
> - Terms: Read and write access to all term data.
> - Users: Read and write access to all user data. This includes public access to some data for post authors.
> - Meta: Read and write access to metadata for posts, comments, terms, and users, on an opt-in basis from plugins.
> - Settings: Read and write access to settings, on an opt-in basis from plugins and core. This enables API management of key site content
>     values that are technically stored in options, such as site title and
>     byline.

I'm not sure what version you tested, but I just tested `4.7-beta4-39320` and it seems to have the above endpoints.

You can checkout the changeset in the ticket.

We can e.g. see the new REST controllers here: [`/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/9b23ccfc298598f23de5c890f8083da0276623d3/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints)